# How to read binary data and send as attachment?

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp

I have in my DataBase data that is actually PDF file

```
command = " select pdffile from pdftable where ...."
```

and I have the next code:

```
OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.Read() && !reader.IsDBNull(1))
            {
                byte[] BytesData = (byte[])reader["BOOKC_ATTACHMENT"];
                Response.ContentType = "application/force-download";
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
                                   "attachment; filename=\"" +
                                   Path.GetFileName((string)reader["BOOKC_ATTACHMENT_NAME"]) + "\"");
                Response.AddHeader("Expires", "0");
                Response.BinaryWrite(BytesData);
                Response.End();
            }
            reader.Close();
            reader.Dispose();
```

It reads the data from the database and creates a PDF file from it and then offers it as a download.

Now, I don't want to download it, I want to send it with SMTP to an email address:

```
MailMessage mm = new MailMessage();
            mm.Subject = strSubject;
            mm.Body = strHtmlBody;
            mm.From = "xxx@xxx.com";
            mm.To = "xx@xx.com";

    Attachment att = new Attachment();
            att. ????
            mm.Attachments.Add(att);

SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["msg_ben_from"],
                                                         ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["msg_ben_pwd"]);
                smtp.Send(mm);
```

Can someone help me to solve it please?

Answer (score 1):

Simply construct a stream from byte[] array and pass it to attachment constructor.
Like:

```
// assuming byte[] BytesData = something at this point
var att = new Attachment(new MemoryStream(BytesData, false), 
  "file.pdf", "application/pdf");
```